# I can't find gnome-system-tools in gconf-editor

Tags: gnome, gconf

I'm trying to turn on fix show all users in the gnome configuration editor.  All the sites I've found say to go to apps -> gnome-system-tools -> users, only I'm not seeing gnome-system-tools anywhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with `fix show all users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was never a sufficient answer.  I ended up doing this through command-line even though tutorials showed it possible through the GUI.  Most of this is moot nowadays as a result of all the GUI updates in the past couple of releases.

Answer (score 3):

Before answering the question, I want to comment on the answer of *gokulvarma* and the conversation between *gokulvarma* and *daniel*:

Having no sudo permission is not the reason of *daniel*'s failure to add **System Tools** to **Applications** menu. He couldn't add it because he tried to add an empty category. **System Tools** is a **category** or a **sub-menu**, if we add an application which will fall under any category, that category is automatically created. On the other hand, if there's nothing under it, we can't create the category; when we try, the tick disappears in some seconds. If we clear all elements under a category, category is cleared automaticaly.

*daniel* tried to add that category by selecting **Applications** from the **left pane** and ticking the **System Tools** from the **right pane**. Like this:

[image]

Instead, he should select **System Tools** from the **left pane** -which is already visible there- and he should tick **Configuration Editor** from the **right pane**. Like this:

[image]

When he is done, in his **Applications** menu, **System Tools** category/sub-menu should appear with **Configuration Editor** in it. Like this:

[image]

There's no need to be a sudoer to do this because the tool we are adding can be used by any user to arrange his/her own preferences.

But will this tool, **Configuration Editor**, help daniel to solve his problem? In my opinion, it won't, because this is the same of what he calls **gconf-editor**. Either via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or via Terminal, `gconf-editor` command will open that application and it sounds that *daniel* already can reach that application but he can't find **gnome-system-tools** in it. He wants to find the gnome-system-tools there in order to reach **users** section of it.

In my **Configuration Editor**, which can be accessed by comand line as well, I can't see something as **gnome-system-tools**, too. neither can I find **users** section. Maybe its somewhere there hidden under some category or it isn't there anymore. (GNOME setting managers have evolved a lot, recently; the sites *daniel* told about might be a old) lets refer to GNOME System Tools' official documentation: [What are the GNOME System Tools?](http://projects.gnome.org/gst/) There, among others, we see a screenshot of the tool to manage users and groups:

[image]

And this is the tool that we know as **Users and Groups**.(Yes interface is slightly changed, but this is it.) It can be reached via System->Administration. So, there's no need to struggle to reach it from inside other tools. Its there. But as Bobby who commented on the question, I couldn't get well what "*fix show all users*" means.

Comment: I just guided him to System tools. Anyways many thanks for educating me. was a gud one.

Comment: Amazing answer, but this is what I'm talking about: http://coder.kidsreturn.org/2010/05/advanced-svn-give-svn-a-web-interface/  About halfway down the page (search for "fix show all") you'll see the reference that gets me stuck.  I can get to the user settings fine, but I want to add system users to a group, not just human ones.  I did it through command line, but all the tutorials (even recent ones) suggest that I can do it through GUI.

Comment: **daniel**, would you please supply some links of that recent tutorials. By the way I am learning as well. And I prefer GUI ways mostly, if they exist.:) **Edit..: OK I googled and found some of them. No need for links. I'll try to understand their way.

Answer (score 0):

**right click on the Menu** select **Edit Menus** and check **System tools**

Comment: hmmm... that seemed promising.  When I check "System Tools" it immediately unchecks itself.

Comment: and that I think is because you need sudo permissions on your login.

Comment: In my opinion it has nothing to do with sudo permission; I'll try to explain it in my anwer because I want to use some screenshots. There, I hope to answer the original question itself.